# holomorphic at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $|z|>1$, let $g(z)=f(1/z)$. Can we say $g(z)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$? If not, please tell me the definition of $f(z)$ is holomorphic at $\infty $ and what conditions $g(z)$ need to satisfy that can lead to $g(z)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$

Comment: Yes. Since $g$ is bounded on some neighbourhood of $0$, it can only have removable singularities within.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of a function being holomorphic at infinity ($g$ being holomorphic at $0$). If $f$ is entire, this means it must be constant, but you can say with this definition that functions like $f(z) = 1/z$ are holomorphic at infinity. (We're really working our way towards talking about holomorphic functions on projective space here.)

Comment: Both thank you so much!